# Como posso usar mais de uma função no mesmo Thread?(python)

Tags: python, funções, thread, função-anônima

Já tentei isso mas diz que a não está definido:

```
import threading as te
import time
b=[]
def c():
  global a
  a=0
  while b==[]:
    time.sleep(0.001)
    a+=0.001
def i():
  b.append(input('enter'))
  print(f'{a:.9}')
r=lambda x: print(x)
te.Thread(target=c and r('c')).start()
i()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o erro. Tentei em Linux e Windows e resultado foi o mesmo `c
enter`

Comment: Deixa pra lá já descobri como fazer; É só colocar mais de um função dentro de outra função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, seria esta a solução que procura?

```
import threading
import time


def printar_um():
    for x in range(0, 5):
        print("\nprintar_um")
        time.sleep(1.0)


def printar_dois():
    for x in range(0, 5):
        print("\nprintar_dois")
        time.sleep(1.0)


def run_thread(job_function):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_function)
    job_thread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_thread(job_function=printar_um)
    run_thread(job_function=printar_dois)
```